# gfortran: Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am compiling a code using gfortran and am getting the error:

tui:~/SCRIPTS/FORTRAN> gfortran -c pulser_ensemble_m.f
pulser_ensemble_m.f:73.18:

```
  OPEN(UNIT=1, NAME=FOUT,ACCESS='SEQUENTIAL',TYPE='NEW')            
              1
```

Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)

**The section of code is copied below::**

```
  FOUT = TEXTIN('ENTER FILTER, ENSEMBLE AVERAGE FILE','-')
  OPEN(UNIT=1, NAME=FOUT,ACCESS='SEQUENTIAL',TYPE='NEW')
```

Comment: Q:  Please [Edit] your question, and show us your declaration for variable "FOUT".  Please consider using a unit# 10 or higher (vs. "1")

Comment: Do you have an unprintable character between the comma and `name`?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and see [ask] and [mcve]. Show a bigger piece of code and copy and paste it exactly so that we can test your problem ourselves. All entities appearing in your example ahould be declared.

Answer (score 1):

NAME is not a valid parameter in an OPEN statement. Here is a minimal example `test.f90`:

```
program test

character (len = *), parameter :: file_name = 'test.txt'
integer, parameter :: u=11

open (unit = u, name = file_name, status = 'new')
write (u, *) 'hello world!'
close (u)
end program test
```

Once compiled and run, it will give

```
test.f90:6:18:

6 |   open (unit = u, name = file_name, status = 'new')
  |                  1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
```

But if you replace `name = file_name` with `file = file_name`, the code will compile correctly and you will write the dummy text into the file.